# Installing Windows XP from USB, PC refuses to boot working bootable USB

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, usb

I have to reinstall Windows XP on my old PC. Installing via USB is the only option - the CD/DVD drive doesn't work anymore, as well as the floppy drive and the computer can't start, the startup just keep looping endlessly.

I made a bootable Windows XP flash drive from my laptop, I tested booting the USB on the laptop and it worked fine, the Windows XP setup started normally.

I plugged the USB in my PC, I adjusted the BIOS boot order accordingly, and the PC refuses to boot the flash drive.

Then I removed all options from the BIOS menu, and I left out USB as the only option (I removed floppy, CD, HDD) to force my PC to boot the USB.

I get:

"Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media. Insert Boot Media in selected boot device and press a key."

What can I do?

Comment: Neverming, managed to figure this out on my own - the USB itself was disabled in the advanced options in the BIOS. I enabled it, and setup started smoothly. I successfully re-installed Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a motherboard from ASUS that wouldn't boot from USB unless you went through the one-time boot menu.  It didn't matter if you told the BIOS that is was a USB FDD, a USB HDD, or some third "USB" option; it simply never worked.

Instead, when you boot, try hitting F12 repeatedly.  With some BIOS's, this will bring up a menu to select the device to boot from.  Hopefully the USB drive will be listed there.  It worked for me :)

Good luck.

Comment: I tried hitting F12, nothing happened.

Comment: Hmm. Different BIOS's have different methods. On my Lenovo, it's the enter key. On a Dell, it's F12. You have to time it right, similar to getting the computer to show the BIOS setup... What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: BIOS Version: K8Upgrade-NF3 BIOS P1.60;   Processor: AMD Semphron 1.6 GHz;   The BIOS menu is opened by hitting F2, but all I can do there is set the BOOT order. USB is already on top.

Answer (score -1):

Insert your bootable device and then restart your machine and in starting you continuously press 'Esc' key it open a window that ask for choose bootable device. and choose your use device.

Comment: try my answer i did this way